# TexStudio cannot compile

Tags: texstudio, macos

I've recently (this week) updated my MacOS to Monterey 12.0.1 as well as the last TexStudio release (4.1.2). Previously all was working properly, but now TexStudio cannot compile.

In fact if I select ">>" i get:

```
Error: Could not start the command: Compile & View
```

And with ">":

```
Process started: PdfLaTeX
```

but then nothing happens. How can I solve this? Is due to the software update?

Comment: In the title of your posting, you mention that you can't compile your document if **TeXshop** is the front-end, and you selected 'texshop' as one of the tags. However, in the body of the posting, you mention that you cannot get a document to compile if **TeXstudio** is the front-end. Please clarify.

Comment: Please also tell us which version of MacTeX you employ and when you last updated it.

Comment: Sorry for the mess, I edited my question

Comment: Please do also tell us which TeX distribution you employ and when you last updated it.

Comment: How can I get such information?

Comment: It mostly sounds like you lost your LaTeX installation when you upgraded your Mac. You can try opening a terminal at see if `which latex` returns anything. If not, it might be easiest to reinstall MacTeX.

Comment: i get ```/Library/TeX/texbin/latex```

Comment: Then that sounds normal. Can you share an image of the settings page in texstudio

Comment: Yes, which in particular? The compiler one? I have the Italian version of TexStudio

Comment: TeXStudio is a so-called "front end"; it is *not* -- repeat: **NOT** -- the program that actually compiles your LaTeX document. For that, you need a TeX distribution, or "back end".  Do please go to the [MacTeX download page](https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) and download and install the latest version of MacTeX. Then see if you can compile your document successfully.

Comment: @Mico when `which latex` returns `/Library/TeX/texbin/latex` in a terminal, then it seems to be there. Might be some PATH settings that got lost in the Mac update

Comment: @daleif - I know fully well that you didn't intend your comments to be interpreted in the following manner, but it would appear that the OP has chosen to take your comments as an open invitation to procrastinate and do nothing for now. Since you and I have no clue as to what exactly may have gone wrong during the OS update procedure, I think the single most promising suggestion to the OP still is to download and install MacTeX2021 from scratch -- especially as doing so requires nothing more from the OP than to perform a half dozen mouse clicks and enter the system password no more than twice.

Comment: @Mico I agree, the best solution if the OP is an IT novice, is to reinstall MacTeX. It would just be nice to know what exactly happened. Does the texstudio on mac rely on the $PATH or are they hardcoding in `/Library/TeX/texbin/...`

Comment: @daleif - Given that the OP was confounding TeXshop and TeXstudio initially, I think it's not much of a stretch (and certainly not an insult) to surmise that he/she is a TeX novice, and possibly an IT novice as well. FWIW, I recently updated the OS on my MacBook Air to 12.0.1. "Monterey", and I experienced no problems with my MacTeX installation. That said, I use TeXworks and TeXshop as front-ends; I have no experience with TeXstudio.

Comment: @Mico I re-installed MacTeX, but TexStudio keeps not compiling. Yes I am new to Latex and I indeed confused Macstudio with Macshop because I have them both installed. Texshop is actually working properly but I prefer to work with Texstudio because it is more intuitive.

Comment: @Barbab - Now that you have the TeX distribution up and running successfully -- incidentally, in case you haven't already done so, do please open a command window and execute `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` as well, in order to bring all packages up to date -- you may need to re-install TeXStudio from scratch too.

Comment: Ok I did that and it took a lot. Texstudio keeps not working, should I delete and re-install it?